# KnockoutJS templates and Twitter Bootstrap/JQuery tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap, templating

I have a snippet that loads Twitter Bootstrap tooltip and popover in the onload looking like this:

```
$('i[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({
    placement: "left"
});
```

That works fine with static HTML until I add KnockoutJS templating (some code omitted for brevity):

```
<div class="row-fluid" data-bind="foreach: events.slice(paginationStart, paginationStop())">
    ...
    <li>
        <i class="icon-calendar" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Date"></i> <span data-bind="text: start">event.date</span>
    </li>
    ...
</div>
```

Then the tooltips don't show up at all. I have tried both with anonymous and normal KnockoutJS templates

I think I understand what is going on: KnockoutJS templating is overwriting Twitter Bootstrap initialization since the templating is run onload after importing Twitter Bootstrap JS-files. But I don't know what to do about it. I did try to put the JQuery stuff after ko.applyBindings but that didn't work neither.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems I might be looking for the afterRender property. I'll give it a try.

Comment: post your findings/solution as an answer and approve it to give closure to the question, this way it will help more people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out pretty quick after writing this question, can't believe I missed it. The answer is to do the Twitter Bootstrap Javascript Plugin/JQuery stuff in the afterRender callback from KnockoutJS tempating.

Example: change the attribute to `data-bind="template: { foreach: data, afterRender: bootstrapDecorate }"` and have bootstrapDecorate be a callable function in your knockout model where you run whatever initialization settings you previous had in your body.onload function.

Comment: Extending knockout is pretty awesome and easy.

Comment: According to the doco, it is recommended that a custom binding be used instead of afterRender. See note in Note #7 - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_5_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements

Comment: It might be now, but did you notice that this post is over a year old?